# ERROR in multi ./src/styles.scss when i try to run my angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

when i try to serve my angular application with `ng serve` i get this error.
[image]

that's my angular.json file :

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css",
              "src/assets/scss/material-dashboard.scss",
              "src/assets/css/demo.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
              "node_modules/canvasjs/dist/canvasjs.js"
            ]
          },
```

i already tried to set the path with `../` , `./` and i put it into `{}` but it still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

"node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css"

This file is not present inside the specified path. Please check

Answer (score 1):

the problem is obviously with "angular-bootstrap-md", you should reinstall it and follow the [installation guide](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/installation/) steps carefully.

Comment: Done, Thanks for ur help.